# Apache Conf Fails when specifing an Include conf file

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, configuration, drupal

I have a drupal multi-site installation that works great.  Since I set it up this has been bugging me and I am trying to work out why this doesnt work.

When I reload apache I get the following error when I have the "Include conf.d/ip.conf" line uncommented:

```
allow not allowed here
   ...fail!
```

If I specify the IP addreses as below (they are commented right now) it works!

Any advice or help would be very much grateful (obviously these IP addresses are not the ones I am using).

```
<Directory "/home/d/r/drupal/web/public_html">
    AllowOverride none

    # Define file limitations on drupal files
    <FilesMatch "(install.php|cron.php|update.php|\.txt)$">
        Order deny,allow
#=================================================================
# THIS DOES NOT WORK? I GET AN ERROR RESTARTING APACHE FOR IP.CONF
        Include conf.d/ip.conf
#=================================================================
# SO I MANUALLY ADD THE IP ADDRESSES HERE:
#Allow from 123.123.123.123
#Allow from 222.222.222.222
#Allow from 555.555.555.555
        Deny from all
    </FilesMatch>

   <FilesMatch "robots.txt">
      Allow from all
   </FilesMatch>

    # Read in Drupal default .htaccess file asif conf - easier CVS management
    Include /home/d/r/drupal/web/public_html/.htaccess

        # Offline mode for multisite setup - see file for more info
        # Uncomment the line below to set sites offline
    # Include conf.d/offline.conf

</Directory>

# Sorry, no svn peeking
<DirectoryMatch "\.svn">
    # Currently pointing back to drupal
    # High traffic sites might want custom
    # error pages, no need to load drupal
    ErrorDocument 403 /index.php
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy All
</DirectoryMatch>

# Allow the .htacces files to be used in the sites folder where /files are stored
<Directory "/home/d/r/drupal/web/public_html/sites">
    AllowOverride
</Directory>
```

ip.conf looks like this:

```
Allow from 123.123.123.123
Allow from 222.222.222.222
Allow from 555.555.555.555
```

Comment: I found the problem, my apache2.conf was including * files in conf.d which is where I have located the drupal6.conf.  This was the reason for the error as it was being loaded by itself!

Comment: Could you please re-post that as an answer and accept it?

Answer (score 1):

This problem was caused because apache2.conf was loading all of the files in conf.d (include conf.d/*) which meant that ip.conf was being loaded in the wrong place. This meant that the `allow from` statements where being processed out of context.